# Coverting string that contains value 12.0 to integer throws Exception

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string returned from a function and the value returned is 12.0 but when I am converting it to Int using Convert.ToInt32(string) or ToInt32.Parse(string) then I am getting an error " Input string is in the incorrect format.

Please help where I am going wrong

Thanks 
priya

Comment: can you please put exact code as this should throw any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32` internally uses [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) which has no support for fractional digits and thus having a trailing .0 causes an exception. You can however use an overload of [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx), namely the one that accepts a [`NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) enumeration:

```
int number = Int32.Parse("12.0", NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the int.TryParse(string val, out int); method
and check any culture related settings 12,0 vs 12.0